# How to make Nelmio ApiDoc annotations pass request method to my forms?

Tags: symfony-forms, fosrestbundle, api-doc

I use dynamic forms (defined as services(!)) to enable/disable some fields for specific request (POST/PUT/PATCH). I want that to be displayed in ApiDoc automatically by passing options to form as [described in documentation](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#form-types-features). But it doesn't work. I use this:

```
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  section = "...",
 *  description = "...",
 *  input = {
 *      "class" = "my_form_type_alias",
 *      "options" = {"method" = "PUT"},
 *      "name" = ""
 *  },
 *  statusCodes = {
 *      200 = "Updated (seems to be OK)",
 *      400 = "Bad request (see messages)",
 *      401 = "Unauthorized, you must login first",
 *      404 = "Not found",
 *  }
 * )
```

But via xdebug I can see that $options['method'] always is equal to 'POST', like when I don't specify "options" = {"method" = "PUT"}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is fixed in Nelmio ApiDoc and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try including the request method in your routing.

By having the ApiDoc correctly configured, method will be shown in ApiDoc.

i.e.

in app/config/routing.yml

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```